# React-table not rendering the cell values

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-table

Columns are getting rendered but not the cell values, I tried console.log in the component file, it is coming. But why not render in the actual cell

```
const tableInstance = useTable({ columns, data });
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = tableInstance;
console.log(typeof columns,{columns});

console.log(typeof data,{data});
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactBootStrap.Table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map(row => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
      </ReactBootStrap.Table>
    </div>
  )
```

[image]
Also double checked the accessor with the response, I'm not using one of the columns from the response in my table, is that the reason? Can't figure this out at all

Comment: share complete code (component)

Comment: this is not the complete code. create a codesandbox in order to help you